# gulp-html-replace not replacing entire block

Tags: gulp, gulp-html-replace

I have a gulp task that opens an index.html file and replaces two build/block with other content.  I am using "gulp-html-replace": "^1.6.0"

One of these blocks is not performing the replace correctly.

Here is the **gulp task**:

```
gulp.task("html:bundle", ['html:clean', 'html:copy'], function () {
    gulp.src('./src/index.html')
    .pipe(htmlReplace({
        'APPJS': '/DesktopModules/regentsigns-app/dist/app.min.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
})
```

Here is the **html block** that needs to be replaced:

```
<!-- build:APPJS -->
<script>System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });</script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Here is the **result**:

```
<script src="/DesktopModules/regentsigns-app/dist/app.min.js"></script>

stem.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });</script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

As you can see, the replace injects the new text but does not fully remove the existing text.

Can someone help me figure out why this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seem to occur for me if the source file was already in the destination folder.  I would make sure you don't have a task that is placing your index.html file in the dist folder before your bundle task.

Comment: Actually it looks like it was because the copy tasks was running simultaneously as the bundle tasks.  So I resorted to using run-sequence to make sure my copy completed before my bundling and this resolved my issue.

Comment: thanks a lot,  the problem was the file already existing from another simultaneous task.  I clean up my tasks to isolate this index file form all the other html I was moving in the gulp task.